# sapui5 filter based on isNull or isNotNull

Tags: filter, null, sapui5

I need to show all data where column data is `Null` or `NOT Null`, that is similar to `SQL` operator `ISNULL`. I have tried with `sap.ui.model.filteroperator` but not getting anything compare for `NULL`. If you know the solutions please help.

Comment: Are you using a mock server? If yes, there is a related issue here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1955.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html)

for example,

1. **EQ** : new Filter(*your_path*, [*FilterOperator.EQ*](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.html), ""); // Show only those fields whose values is **equal** to empty
2. **NE**: new Filter(*your_path*, [*FilterOperator.NE*](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.html), ""); // Show only those fields whose values is **not equal** to empty

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But unfortunately database is holding NULL so empty string is not working with it. In SQL you can compare empty string (length = 0) with this way but to perform operation with NULL need only ISNULL, so its similar here also.

Answer (score 2):

As @Prashob said, you can use the filter construct. You can use it with the "null" keyword as well. Example:

```
oTable.getBinding("items").filter([new Filter("property", "EQ", null)])
```

Or in an XML view:

```
<Table items="{
    path: '/collection', 
    filters: [{path: 'property', operator: 'EQ', value1: null}]
}">
```

If you are using a JSONModel, then this will work without any issues. If you are using an OData service, then it depends a little on the backend. Normally, it should work (e.g. see the Northwind service; it supports null comparison: http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=Region%20eq%20null); the underlying implementation should know to translate the OData filter into an appropriate WHERE clause (i.e. `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`)

Comment: In HANA I am publishing calculation view in odata, so where I can write WHERE clause? I can not see any scope to write SQL in graphical view publication on odata.

Comment: I did not state that you should write it. The XSODATA "framework" that you are using to publish the calculation view does the "translation" automatically. The only question is if it does it correctly or not,

Comment: @SumanBiswas, are you using OData service? If yes, check Nullable Properties at https://blogs.sap.com/2014/12/02/sap-hana-sps-09-new-developer-features-new-xsodata-features/ . You need to set  to support null.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you project on the column of your VDM view to a new calculated attribute. Converting the value based on `isnull` function to a Empty string.

```
if(isnull("Column"),'',"Column")
```

Answer (score 0):

**String Data Type** can hold `null` and `""` value
and hence depends on if you want to filter both
you would need to query for both i.e.

```
oTable.getBinding("items").filter([
new Filter("property", "EQ", null), 
new Filter("property", "EQ", "")
])
```

**non-String data types**:
can hold only `null` and hence you can query

```
oTable.getBinding("items").filter([new Filter("property", "EQ", null)])
```